# Certain characters don't appear in all windows

Tags: 14.04, fonts, window

Running Ubuntu 14.04. The last thing I installed was Dropbox. After restarting my computer, certain characters will no longer display. This happens on all windows, like Firefox, Nautilus, or even the calculator. I've also had a hard time Googling for stuff because I'm not sure what to look for.

Any help or advice would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: What video card/driver are you using?

Comment: When I did `lspci | grep "VGA"`, I got this: "Intel Cooperation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)". I have a dedicated graphics card installed too, but it appears that Ubuntu hasn't noticed.

Comment: Can you try changing the text scaling factor?